# Refreshing an Elastic Search Index / Realtime Searching

Tags: real-time, elasticsearch

I'm writing unit tests for an ElasticSearch datasource, however, I am getting mixed results. The problem is that a match_all query isn't finding records that I submitted, however, when I run the commands by hand using CURL in the same order the unit test does I am able to find the records.

I believe that perhaps the index isn't refreshed, so, I started running the "refresh" api command after submitting records, however, this didn't work either. Here is my list of commands - it would be helpful if anyone had any suggestions on how to make sure these commands worked even if they were run in immediate succession.

Commands the unit test runs:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test_index/_mapping'

curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/test_index/test_models'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test_index/test_models/_refresh' -d '{}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test_index/test_models/_mapping' -d '{"test_models":{"properties":{"TestModel":{"properties":{"id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"string":{"type":"string"},"created":{"type":"date","format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"},"modified":{"type":"date","format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}},"type":"object"}}}}'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test_index/test_models/_bulk' -d '{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"test_models","_id":"test-model"}}
{"TestModel":{"id":"test-model","string":"Analyzed for terms","created":"2012-01-01 00:00:00","modified":"2012-02-01 00:00:00"}}
'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test_index/test_models/_refresh' -d '{}'

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test_index/_mapping'

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test_index/test_models/_search' -d '{"query":{"match_all":{}},"size":10}'
```

This question has also been posted to the (super awesome) ElasticSearch mailing list:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/elasticsearch/Nxv0XpLDY4k

-DK

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with the _refresh command.

You can't refresh a type, only an index. I changed the refresh command to:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test_index/_refresh'
```

And it is now fixed!